# How to convince my client to go for responsive webdesign?

Tags: responsive-design, client

I've worked with my client in the past and only recently some problems appeared and I started to work again on some things. Meanwhile they have created a mobile version of their website, but unfortunately they created two different designs instead of choosing a responsive design.

This decision was taken because the mobile version was considered "not good enough as a desktop option". I'd like to convince my client to reconsider this and in fact work out a responsive version of the website.

When I google "why responsive" I get [some](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/john-rampton/business-mobile-responsive-design_b_5267077.html) [great](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2253965/3-Reasons-Why-Responsive-Web-Design-is-the-Best-Option-For-Your-Mobile-SEO-Strategy) [results](http://www.webstarsltd.com/blog/why-responsive-web-design-is-important), but I'm not sure if sending some links will cut it in this case (most links are specifically about responsive vs. non-responsive, not responsive vs. different mobile/desktop site).

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: I googled "[why not responsive](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=why+not+responsive&search_plus_one=form)" and got some good results too. :)

Comment: could be interesting: https://whichtestwon.com/test/mobile-site-increased-leads-ppc-traffic/?utm_source=Newsletter&utm_medium=Email&utm_content=Text-LinkA&utm_campaign=RasmussenTOTW

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the site already exists.

**The best place to start is to look at existing Analytics** to see what the popular breakpoints are for his site. It helps clients visualize when you can make statements specific to their case.

The approach would be to examine:

1. If the current site is meeting the needs of most browsing preferences.
2. How the current mobile site is NOT meeting the needs of most browsing preferences. (Example: Are there more bounces because the mobile site doesn't work on their Tablet?)

and go from there.

With such a diverse screen range nowadays, it's always better to cater to the audience.

You can also argue that making the site responsive will:

1. allow it to be more future forward, and;
2. cuts down on develop costs by reducing the amount of redesigns needed so they don't have to keep adapting as new technologies come out. This may include a large upfront cost and one time development fee but saves in the long run. Many people get sticker shock and so it's harder for them to get past this.

If all of the above do not work, you can also show him some related examples of how other designers were able to preserve the primary desktop content within the responsive versions.

Hope this helps. Good luck!